# Faulty pseudo selector

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to change the properties of "special-offer-left-block" and "special-offer-right-block" with the pseudo :hover on "special-offer-breaker" but it seems like I select them incorrect. Any ideas on what I do wrong?

Nothing happens when I hover, but I want the background colors to change! :)

Hope anyone here can help me!

http://codepen.io/oskarscholander/pen/zBpRwV

```
<div class="special-offer-container">
  <div class="special-offer-breaker"></div>
  <div class="special-offer-left-block"></div>
  <div class="special-offer-right-block"></div>
</div>


$orange: #FFFF00

.special-offer-container
    position: relative
    width: 100%
    background: $orange
    height: 400px
    display: block

.special-offer-left-block   
    width: 50%
    height: 100%
    background: darken($orange, 20%)
    float: left
    display:inline
    transition: (background 2s ease-in)

.special-offer-right-block  
    width: 50%
    height: 100%
    background: lighten($orange, 30%)
    display: inline
    float: right
    transition: (background 2s ease-in)

.special-offer-breaker
    z-index: 4
    position: absolute
    margin: auto
    left: 0
    right: 0
    top: 0
    bottom: 0
    display: inline
    background: lighten($orange, 40%)
    border-radius: 75px
    width: 150px
    height: 150px
    &:hover
        .special-offer-left-block
            background: #333333

        .special-offer-right-block
            background: #333333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you wrote it would've worked if`special-offer-left-block`and `special-offer-right-block` were child elements of the `special-offer-breaker`, but instead, all 3 of them are siblings so

you need to use the general sibling selector `~`

you could also use `+` for `.special-offer-left-block` and `~` only for `.special-offer-right-block` because `.special-offer-left-block` is directly after the `special-offer-breaker`

there are a number of ways to do this specific example. but i suggest doing like so :

```
&:hover
    ~ .special-offer-left-block
        background: #333333

    ~ .special-offer-right-block
        background: #333333
```

*The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.*

for more information see here **[General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)**